# how to add credentials from the command line using 'git credential-osxkeychain store'?

Tags: git, macos

When executing 'git credential-osxkeychain' in MacOS, it shows the option 'store' and I guess it can be used to add the credentials.

I didn't find any documentation about the syntax required to add credentials using the command 'git credential-osxkeychain store', anyone knows how to do it?

Please notice that I do know how to do it using the MacOS app 'Keychain Access', I'd like to know how to do it using the command line

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`git credential-osxkeychain store` [reads protocol/host/username/password](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f4e64169352e03476b0ea64e7e2973669e491a2/contrib/credential/osxkeychain/git-credential-osxkeychain.c#L113) from stdin separated by newlines, so feed them something like this:

```
echo "\
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=$NAME
password=$PASSWD" | git credential-osxkeychain store
```

All 4 parameters are [required](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f4e64169352e03476b0ea64e7e2973669e491a2/contrib/credential/osxkeychain/git-credential-osxkeychain.c#L103).

Comment: if anyone's having trouble with the multi-line text, what you can do is copy everything from protocol to PASSWD into a file and then `cat thefile | git credential-osxkeychain store` (and don't forget do delete the file once you're done)

Comment: Hmmm, newlines...try: `echo -e "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\nusername=$NAME\npassword=$PASSWD" | git credential-osxkeychain store`